# Can the HuggingFace GPT2DoubleHeadsModel be used for non-multiple-choice next token prediction?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, gpt-2

According to the HuggingFace Transformer's website (https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/gpt2.html#gpt2doubleheadsmodel), **GPT2DoubleHeadsModel** (NOT **GPT2LMHeadModel** but **GPT2DoubleHeadsModel**) is the GPT-2 transformer model with a language modelling and a multiple-choice classification head on top e.g. for RocStories/SWAG tasks.

Does this mean that we can use the **GPT2DoubleHeadsModel** to process both non-multiple-choice-based language modelling tasks (i.e. next word prediction) as well as the multiple-choice questions, without making any adjustment to its head? Or would I need to adjust the head of the **GPT2DoubleHeadsModel** if I want to do the non-multiple-choice-based next word predictions because the **GPT2DoubleHeadsModel** is for answering multiple-choice type questions only?

I am a bit confused by this because the impression that I got from reading your GPT-2 paper is that GPT-2 uses language modelling process to process every type of language task (therefore GPT-2 would only have the regular language modelling head at the top), yet the name "**GPT2DoubleHeadsModel**" seem to suggest that I need to adjust the head of this GPT-2 for different types of language tasks.

Thank you,